# Increase scope outside of ngif-tag?

Tags: angularjs

In angular I have a bit of template that looks like this:

```
                <div ng-if="fieldset.expandable">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                    <input 
                        ng-model="checked"
                        value="ignore"
                        type="checkbox"
                    >
                        {{fieldset.expandable}}
                        {{checked}}

                    </label>

                </div>
```

When I have the ng-if attribute, the {{checked}} only works inside that part of the DOM. Outside of that, it is just empty. Why is this and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ng-if` directive creates a new scope. Use an object:

```
<!-- works outside ng-if as well -->
{{obj.checked}}
<div ng-if="fieldset.expandable">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input ng-model="obj.checked" value="ignore" type="checkbox">
            {{fieldset.expandable}}
            {{obj.checked}}
    </label>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.obj = {"checked":""};
```